# Doctrine - Difference between injected entities in entity listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

As we can see in [official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) Doctrine implements entity listeners which are executed only when something happens on a specific entity.

However there is a different injection between lifecycle event listeners/subscribers and entity listeners. In fact for listeners/subscribers Doctrine injects only a `LifecycleEventArgs` object into defined callbacks

```
// Event listener/subscriber
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
}
```

which gives you anyway access to the entity, but then in an entity listener the entity is also injected explicitly as first argument

```
// Entity listener
public function postUpdate(object $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity2 = $args->getEntity();
}
```

and it's still available in `$args`. This is also reported in documentation:

> An entity listener method receives two arguments, the entity instance
>   and the lifecycle event.

But then what's exactly the difference between `$entity` and `$args->getEntity()` in an entity listener?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same entity.

As `LifecycleEventArgs` is injected even in "generic" doctrine listener, you need to retrieve entity object. On the others side the `LifecycleEventArgs` has a lot of things you can retrieve in both situation.

For this rease, they've used the same object for both operations: it's pretty common and acceptable from my POV.

You can verify it yourself by doing something like

```
// Entity listener
public function postUpdate(object $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity2 = $args->getEntity();
    dump(spl_obj_hash($entity) == spl_obj_hash($entity)); // you can echo this, or log, or VarDump, or whatever
}
```

Comment: Yes but the point is not why `LifecycleEventArgs` is injected but rather why the entity is explicitly injected when it's already available in `$args`...

Comment: @DrKey Think about testing: having it injected instead of have to stub the call from `args` could be a reason. It's just a "shortcut" to me and it does not add any complexity or whatever to this. I bet is just for those kind of reasons.